# How to show a TextView inside a LinearLayout that is "visibility="gone""

Tags: java, android-studio

i'm actually really new at coding in java and on AndroidStudio and i'm trying to update an application that already exist.

I have 3 LinearLayout that look like 3 square inside each other and inside the last one, i have a TewtView.
the first one is the main one and is always visible.
When i put my two last LinearLayout in visibility="GONE" my LinearLayout disapear, and i want that my textView will be always visible, even if the LinearLayout that contains it are invisible.

It is possible?

```
 <LinearLayout
 style="@style/ColPlayer"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:orientation="horizontal" >

 <LinearLayout
 style="@style/SquareBogey"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:layout_width="70dp"
 android:layout_height="50dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:id="@+id/outersquare">

 <LinearLayout
 style="@style/SquareBogey"
 android:visibility="gone"
 android:layout_width="60dp"
 android:layout_height="40dp"
 android:orientation="horizontal"
 android:id="@+id/innersquare">

 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/PlayerCJ01"
 style="@style/ColCJPlayer"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:ems="1" />
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
 </LinearLayout>
```

Just ask me if you need more informations.
Thanks

Comment: Please de-indent your code when pasting it here. It shouldn't be a gazillion indents to the right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of setting the visibility as GONE for the LinearLayouts, maybe you can set their background/border as transparent by changing their style.

It depends on your use case, if it suits your need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i'll need the borders

Comment: When you are setting to gone, obviously the borders are removed. Instead of gone change the style to transparent

Comment: I'll need to make the borders visible or not on some conditions, so can i set in a if what you just said? Like can i put the style to transparent when i need it and make it visible in other conditions?

Comment: Yes you can. Use .setbackgroundresource and similar

Answer (score 2):

When setting the visibility of a parent layout to GONE or INVISIBLE, all its children will also become GONE or INVISIBLE.

If you want to show the `TextView` but not its parent `LinearLayout`, than you could either move the `TextView` out of the `LinearLayout`, or you could remove the styling of the `LinearLayout` so it will look like its gone, but obviously it's still there.

Setting the visibility of the `LinearLayout` to GONE and its child `TextView`'s visibility to VISIBLE won't work and therefore is not an option.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but i need the border to be visible and if i move the TextView out of the LinearLayout, my main LinearLayout is getting bigger and when the other LinearLayout are visible, the TextView is out of them.

Comment: then remove all styling but the border

Comment: The thing is that after i'm done with that, i'll put some if in the Java code that set visible or not the borders, that will depend on other settings of the application